# Pdf Viewer in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, model-view-controller, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am developing an MVC 5 Application. Now I want to use a PDF Viewer in my application. So can any tell me which control I should use in my .CSHTML page. There should be a browse button by clicking this browse button I should open a PDF from local disk.
Also it would be better if there is any Pdf viewer control in Kendo ASP.Net Mvc toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload user existing pdf file or if you already have a pdf file on server's local disk you can open it on the page to change content type of page.

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
response.WriteFile("path");
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.End();
```

Answer (score -1):

you're gonna have a bad time without using 3rd party solutions.

I suggest using [iTextSharp](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/80/create-pdfs-in-asp-net-getting-started-with-itextsharp) it's opensource and there's alot of documentation

Comment: is there any thing with out using 3rd party solutions

Comment: if you read the first sentence of that link I gave you:"The .NET framework does not contain any native way to work with PDF files. "

Comment: iTextSharp / iText can not draw documents. I guess you should not recommend any tool if you have no idea about it's capabilities.